# Turning a circuit off...without touching it

Tags: current, induction

Just a curiosity question;

**Is it possible to reduce current (to almost zero) in the following complete, simple circuit without making ANY physical contact with it?**

[image]

Supposing this can be achieved by a certain procedure, say *X*. Then *X* must:

-Be practical (at a small, DIY scale)

- Not involve any significant change in temperature (not more than 10°C)
- Not involve any deformation/alteration of the circuit or any of it's components.
- Be able to stop current for a good deal of time (at least an hour)
- Be reversible; i.e- the current ought to flow in the circuit again once *X* has been stopped or reversed.

---

P.S- I'm not sure, but since any physical contact is a big no-no, electromagnetic induction may (somehow?) offer a way out.

EDIT :

I believe the post generated some misunderstanding (I appreciate what you guys suggested in the comments, but that isn't what I'm looking for); so I'll make it clear here:

I've *already* provided a diagram of the circuit I have in mind...and one of the conditions was:

> Not involve any deformation/alteration of the circuit or any of it's components.

Meaning; The original circuit must remain intact...no rewiring or replacing of any of those components. **However** it may be incorporated into another, larger circuit.

For example, if my original question did not have the temperature or deformation constraint, I'd consider *inducing* *Eddy currents* in (a part of) the circuit's wiring. That would possibly increase the temperature of the wiring, and thereby increase it's resistance (much like an induction furnace).

Also, if it's any help, I plan on actually carrying this out...so yeah, the circuit (and its components) aren't idealized. Of course I hope to do this on a fairly small scale (simple circuit with about 2 feet of copper wiring).

Comment: Timer relay is doing this without any touch. Even without any presence.

Comment: @Eugene Thanks! But the simple circuit I mentioned doesn't have any though ._.

Comment: Have you googled smart switch? One that is online and is controlled from the cellphone

Comment: A normally closed reed switch and a magnet seems like it would meet your requirements.

Comment: Huh? I don't understand. You want modify a behavior without any modification of the circuit? It is called "magic".

Comment: This is a trick question, isn't it?

Comment: @pjc50 **No** ಠ_ಠ

Comment: About the update: You have a switch on your schematic. Without any other information it is an "ideal" switch. Meaning it does not conduct current when open, and is short when closed. No more assumptions can be made on it given the circuit. So no, *nothing* can make it conduct whenever open and vice-versa.

Comment: @Eugene Note Andy's answer.

Comment: It won't apply to the open circuit.

Comment: @paracresol it has all the hallmarks of those highly constrained single-bizarre-solution "lateral thinking" puzzles that interviewers love.

Comment: @pjc50 I hate puzzles...also I actually plan on carrying this out ._.

Comment: You're going to be disappointed in carrying this out if there are no practical solutions, which I think there aren't; Andy's answer is only viable for very short times.

Comment: Yup ... *sighs*

Comment: Do you have a real problem you are trying to solve? Looks like *XY-problem*.

Comment: @Eugene Well, I wouldn't call it a "problem", really...

Comment: You are trying to solve *something*, aren't you? *Something* requiring a solution is usually referred as *problem*.

Comment: as the switch is not closed, there is no current in the circuit. so you don't need to do anything to achieve the no-current goal. you are done before you even started.

Comment: There's lots of ways to fake this but that's not what you asked.

Comment: Maybe Texas Instruments LDC0851, "Differentially Compensated and Highly Accurate Inductive Switch" and some latches might do the trick for this application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Just a curiosity

Generate a rising magnetic field that induces in the circuit loop a voltage that is equal and opposite to the driving voltage from the battery. This then stops current flow. It's not very practical for holding off current for more than a few seconds (of course) unless you used superconductors.

\$V_{INDUCED} = N\dfrac{d\Phi}{dt}\$ where N = 1 i.e. the loop of the circuit.

\$\dfrac{d\Phi}{dt}\$ is produced by applying a voltage across a loop of wire - a constant rising flux is produced.

Note that the following constraint was edited into the question after I provided my answer above: -

> Be able to stop current for a good deal of time (at least an hour)

Given that all that is shown in the question is a schematic, there is nothing stopping the implementation of that circuit to involve looping the lightbulb feed circuit around 3,600 times (yes I know I'm stretching it a bit). This makes the induced voltage 3,600 times bigger and therefore the rising flux needed to "hold-off the battery voltage can be 3,600 times smaller and this might be able to be generated for an hour.

If it could be done previously for 1 second then it could be done now for 1 hour.

Also note that my answer isn't about inducing eddy currents in the wiring; it's all about Faraday's Law of induction. Having said that some eddy currents would inevitably be induced but use of thin wires pretty much would make this a secondary effect.

Answer (score -1):

As you've posted a picture of an OPEN circuit, I'd hazard that you've already accomplished the task of reducing current to zero.

As a more direct answer to your question: Yes.